# Android - Toggle visible/invisible on multiple imageviews via their ID or TAG

Tags: android, imageview

I have four imageviews which are set to invisible at activity start (or rather at row inflation). I would like to press a button and have them ALL become visible (and subsequently be operational as onclicks...). I have the following summary code, but I keep getting errors whenever I try to access any other imageview other than the last one.

```
public class xx {

    private ImageView up;
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Log.i(TAG, "excersizeAdapter getView");
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }

            Excersize e = items.get(position);
            if (e != null) {
                TextView exTitle      = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ex_type_title);
                TextView exOn         = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ex_on_title);
                TextView exRestAmount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ex_rest_amount);
                TextView exSequence   = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ex_sequence);

                up                    = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.moveup);
                down                  = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.movedown);

                if (exTitle !=null) {
                    exTitle.setText(e.getTypeTitle());
                }

                if (exOn !=null) {
                    exOn.setText("On: "+e.getTypeOn());
                }

                if (exRestAmount !=null) {
                    exRestAmount.setText(e.getRestAmount().toString());
                }

                if (exSequence !=null) {
                    exSequence.setText(e.getSequence().toString());
                    up.setTag(8881);
                    down.setTag(8882);

                    up.setId(((Integer)e.getSequence()));
                    down.setId(((Integer)e.getSequence()));

                    Log.i(TAG, "up,down values=" +e.getSequence());
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }

    public void toggleReorderButtons() {
        up.findViewById(2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        up.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        up.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

OK, this is cut down code, but in the makevisinvis method `up.findview...` it causes a crash and up.setvis, etc. will turn on only the last one that was added to my activity.

I also tried the following with no success.

```
ImageView upper = (ImageView) up.findViewById(2);
upper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

A lovely error dump:

```
04-21 09:10:55.650: W/dalvikvm(22392): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at com.mediabarltd.digittrainer.ProgramDisplay.toggleReorderButtons(ProgramDisplay.java:437)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at com.mediabarltd.digittrainer.ProgramDisplay.onClick(ProgramDisplay.java:391)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
04-21 09:10:55.675: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It took some serious looking and a total rework of what I was doing. but...

Basically I followed the tutorial *[Android ListView and ListActivity](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adaptermodel)* and then implemented the neat 'trick' described in *[Android ListView Adapter OnClickListener issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461134/android-listview-adapter-onclicklistener-issue/4461244#comment13203799_4461244)*.

(I'm really having a hard time with this.)

Comment: according to the posted log NPE happens not in 'makevisinvis'. Can you please double check? also, can you post code that defines/inits up and down objects/

Comment: sorry that was mebeing stupid with my examlpe, I changed the method name when writing it out on SO. i'll update....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `up` as a class member and re-init it every time `getView` gets called - therefore it always points to the last image view created. Also, I am not sure it is correct to call `findViewById` of `up`: instead set its `OnClickListener` inside `getView` and whenever clicked look for the required views inside a layout it belongs to.

Comment: I think you're on to something there. I've just done some checking and the ID is always the last one that id is set against. it must be overwriting the others..

Comment: thanks for the help, I have now sorted out my code and included my solution in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You must give the ImageView an ID, like

```
android:id="@+id/some_name"
```

Then find it like this:

```
up.findViewById(R.id.some_name);
```

Comment: I already did this during the initial inflate process "up       = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.moveup);" Is that what you mean, or do I need to do this again? After I did this I assigned the ID, and thought I'd be able to use that to reference it? (Also I've added this line above)

Comment: How do I then refer individually to each version of the imageview? I thought that was where the setId came in to it?

Comment: in the "public View getView" which is building my row data, I use a unique field from the database and assign this to the Id of the up imageview. this is setting the ID unique, no?

Comment: use setTag method and then use getTag method.

Comment: @ZazGmy that was my first avenue of exploration, but I cannot find how to 'use' a getTag. i.e. up.getTag(8881).setvisible(View.VISIBLE); Doesn't exist for me?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
int i = (int) up.getTag();
if (i == 8881) {
    //Do something here
}
```

Comment: ok I can see how that can act on the existance of my tags, but using this how to I set all 4 of my up imageviews to visible?

Comment: get tag of each imageview and use nested condition.