# Onclick is not working for a button in Listview to fetch TextView in android

Tags: android

I have Two `Buttons` along with the text in `ListView`. Onclick Listener is not working when i click on Button.

The following is my code:

list_details.xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />
```

list_item_details.xml

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/try_it"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:text="tile try" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/download"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    />
```

ListDetailsActivity.java

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.list_details);

productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

new LoadAllProducts().execute();

ListView lv = getListView();

Button download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.download);

download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View view) {

         TextView try_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.try_it);

         String try_text_val = try_txt.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), try_text_val, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  });
 }


protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(

                         ListDetailsActivity.this, productsList,
                    R.layout.list_item_details, new String[] { TAG_TRY_IT},
                    new int[] { R.id.try_it});

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                                    }
            });
   }
  }
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: You can find an example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461244/1007522 it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `android:onClick` in your list row layout, for each button. It may be the most convenient way for this purpose, as almost always.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am able to make it work it with onClick from xml page

Comment: @usd123: You're welcome. Please, check this answer, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the onClick event in your custom adapter. (in getView method)

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting the `OnClickListener` on the first `Button` with id `R.id.download`. When you use `findViewById()` it will only return the first view that has the requested id, even if there are more. Because you are calling it on the `Activity` it has multiple rows in the listview with buttons with that id.

The way to fix it is to do it in your adapter. You are using a `SimpleAdapter`. Make your own adapter class and override the `getView()` function to attach the `OnClickListener` there. Something like this:

```
private class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        View button = view.findViewById(R.id.download);
        button.setOnClickListener( /* ... your code ... */ );
        return view;
    }
}
```

**View Holder design pattern**

In your click handler you are manipulating the `TextView` `R.id.try_it`. So you will need to do a `findViewById()` for that as well on the view you're returning from `getView()`. The View Holder design patter is meant for this use case. My advise is to read the Android tutorial on [Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) to learn how that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I created a custom adapter but i am facing issue with when starting intent using onClick from getView(). below is the code: bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ @Override public void onClick(View v) { Uri uri = Uri.parse("google.com"); Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); context.startActivity(intent); } }); if you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Put the protocol in the uri: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://google.com"));`